# Coding VBA to define "x" textbox to be non-editable after a source DLookup

Tags: vba, ms-access, edit

I need that after this code write the results of the lookup, that same fields become non-editable and then focus on "Texto696"

This is what I have so far.

`UPDATE DE MARCA, MODELO, MOTORIZAÇÃO, ANO INICIO, ANO FIM, DATA MATRICULA, NUMERO DE PORTAS E COMBUSTIVEL QUANDO VFV EXISTIR`

```
Private Sub Comando713_Click()
If Not IsNull(Me!Texto689.Value) Then
    Me!Combinação65.Value = DLookup("[MARCA]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação69.Value = DLookup("[MODELO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto73.Value = DLookup("[ANO INICIAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto75.Value = DLookup("[ANO FINAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação611.Value = DLookup("[NUMERO DE PORTAS]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto445.Value = DLookup("[CODIGO MOTOR]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação435.Value = DLookup("[COMBUSTIVEL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me.Texto696.SetFocus
End If
```

End Sub

I did test this code and nothing happens, still editable.

```
    Me.Combinação65.AllowValueListEdits = False
```

Comment: Anyone knows why i cant make a question and why my question as on -2 in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.Locked = True` property on your controls to stop users from changing data. You can also use the `.Enabled = False` property to stop users from using the control at all.

```vb
Private Sub Comando713_Click()

If Not IsNull(Me!Texto689.Value) Then

    ' Get values

    Me!Combinação65.Value = DLookup("[MARCA]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação69.Value = DLookup("[MODELO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto73.Value = DLookup("[ANO INICIAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto75.Value = DLookup("[ANO FINAL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação611.Value = DLookup("[NUMERO DE PORTAS]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto137.Value = DLookup("[MOTORIZAÇÃO]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Texto445.Value = DLookup("[CODIGO MOTOR]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")
    Me!Combinação435.Value = DLookup("[COMBUSTIVEL]", "[CONSULTA DE VFV INSERIR PEÇAS]")

    ' Make controls non-editable

    Me!Combinação65.Locked = True
    Me!Combinação69.Locked = True
    Me!Texto73.Locked = True
    Me!Texto75.Locked = True
    Me!Texto137.Locked = True
    Me!Combinação611.Locked = True
    Me!Texto137.Locked = True
    Me!Texto445.Locked = True
    Me!Combinação435.Locked = True

    Me!Combinação65.Enabled = False
    Me!Combinação69.Enabled = False
    Me!Texto73.Enabled = False
    Me!Texto75.Enabled = False
    Me!Texto137.Enabled = False
    Me!Combinação611.Enabled = False
    Me!Texto137.Enabled = False
    Me!Texto445.Enabled = False
    Me!Combinação435.Enabled = False

    Me.Texto696.SetFocus

End If
```

Comment: thanks for the suport. Indeed the text field become blocked but i only want it to be blocked if `Me!Texto689.Value` its not null and only after the Dlookup shows its results on the text box. I tested it but it lock the field as soon as the form is loaded.

Comment: The code is all triggered on the click event of a command button, so it shouldn't lock on the form's load event.